# SQL 'WHERE' versus 'ON' (inner join)

Tags: sql

When doing an SQL query,

is there any significant (or any at all) difference in performance between 'WHERE' and 'ON'?

I know there is a significant difference in the resulting set between the two for a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN.

What about an INNER JOIN?

Is there any drawback to using 'ON' for each of my selects rather than 'WHERE' at the end?

Comment: Did you even *try* to [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+%27WHERE%27+versus+%27ON%27+%28inner+join%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)? [It's the first result on Google, and it's even right on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause).  :(

Comment: No, but use ON, please

Comment: But don't use the `IN` operator; in this case a JOIN is a lot faster ...

Comment: Here's another heavily upvoted [possible dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1018822/119477)

Comment: I think here's a similar thread with good explanation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise, they should be the same. However, see [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) article for an opinion of an industry veteran regarding the readability and maintenace-friendliness.

While the old-style joins still work, you can't do an `outer join` [anymore](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2008/09/13/deprecation-of-old-style-join-syntax-only-a-partial-thing.aspx?Redirected=true)

Answer (score 1):

Execution plans for both are identical. Many people prefer the use of `ON` though.